# How do I compile the string value from angular's ui-ace to actual HTML

Tags: angularjs

What i am trying to figured out is how to compile the string values from Ace editor. As you can see i get the strings with out compiling. I appreciate all the help. Thanks

```
<div ui-ace="{onLoad: aceLoaded,onChange: aceChanged}" ng-model="aceModel" class="ace_editor"></div>
   <textarea id="ace_document"> {{aceDocumentValue}}</textarea>

 app.controller('AceCtrl', function ($scope) {
    // select
      $scope.modes = ['CoffeeScript','ColdFusion'];
      $scope.mode = $scope.modes[0];


     $scope.aceLoaded = function(_editor) {
     mode: $scope.mode.toLowerCase(),
    $scope.aceSession = _editor.getSession();
     _editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");

      // options
           _editor.setOptions({
            showGutter: true,
            showPrintMargin: false,
            fontSize: '14px',
            fontFamily: 'menlo'
           });
           // HACK to have the ace instance in the scope...
          $scope.modeChanged = function () {
            _editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/" + $scope.mode.toLowerCase());
          };
    };
    $scope.aceChanged = function () {
        $scope.aceDocumentValue = $scope.aceSession.view.contents().getValue();
    };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a custom directive and use $compile to compile it to actual HTML.

See the documentation on directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive and on $compile: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

```
angular.module('app').directive('compiler', [
    '$compile',
    function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                scope.$watch(attributes.html, function (html) {
                    element.html(html);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Put the new compiler element into your template:

```
<div ui-ace="{
    onLoad: aceLoaded,
    onChange: aceChanged
}"></div>
<compiler html="aceDocumentValue"></compiler>
```

In your controller get the value and assign it to your scope:

```
angular.module('app').controller('rootController', [
    '$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.aceLoaded = function(_editor) {
            $scope.aceSession = _editor.getSession();
        };
        $scope.aceChanged = function () {
            $scope.aceDocumentValue = $scope.aceSession.getDocument().getValue();
        };
    }
]);
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/pHhDX7RBR1YmYbTG8PXT?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for that...... you just made my day dude...... how about if i want to compile to different languages???

Comment: Good question :) `$compile` only compiles HTML, although inline javascript `<button onclick="alert()">Click</button>` works but `<script>` blocks don't. I guess if you want to compile javascript, you'de use JSON.parse() and then eval that, but i've never done something like that before, it's far out of my comfortzone and people say that eval is evil. But i could be wrong on the `<script>` block compiling. I think this warrants a new question, which i can't answer. I'm sorry.